# No animation on linear progress indicator when adding statuslistener

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

My LinearProgressIndicator does not animate forward when I add AddStatusListener. I get the build method re-rendering after the animation is completed, but there is no linear animation happening. I want the animation to run and just after it is completed I need a widget to appear, here in this case the Text widget.

Here is my code -

```
class _AuthenticationPageState extends State<AuthenticationPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  late AnimationController controller;
  bool test = false;
    @override
      void initState() {
        controller = AnimationController(
          vsync: this,
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
        )..addStatusListener((AnimationStatus status) {
          setState(() {
            if(status == AnimationStatus.completed) test = true;
          });
        });
        controller.forward();
        super.initState();
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        controller.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30,50,10,30),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const Text('Hello, Welcome', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 60),),
                LinearProgressIndicator(
                  value: controller.value,
                  semanticsLabel: 'Linear progress indicator',
                ),
                if(test == true) const Text('Test is true')
              ],
            )
          ),
        );
      }
```

Comment: *"[...] but there is no linear animation happening"* - this is because your `build` method is not called after each controller tick - to do that you can for example add listener (and not only status listener what you did) on your controller

Comment: @pskink Could you put the code as an answer? Just want to see how I can add both listener and statuslistener.

Comment: `..addListener(() => setState(() {}))`

Comment: it does not work, you said to addListener and addStatusListener on your previous comment, how do we add both. Please be clear and also if you post the code as an answer, really appreciate it.

Comment: just add the above code after `..addStatusListener(...)` - so it looks: `controller = AnimationController(...)..addStatusListener(...)..addListener(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing changing because you are not listening every tick, you're only listening to when its done, as [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) tried to explain in the comments.

```
 void initState() {
        controller = AnimationController(
          vsync: this,
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
        )
          ..addStatusListener((AnimationStatus status) {
            setState(() {
              if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) test = true;
            });
          })
          ..addListener(() {
            setState(() {});
          });
        controller.forward();
        super.initState();
      }
```

Comment: Thanks Yasine, I really appreciate the code. Being a newbie to flutter, only actual code makes sense to me.